# The equivalent proposition of Legendre's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

[Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture), proposed by Adrien-Marie Legendre, state that there is a prime number between $n^2$  and $(n+1)^2$ for every positive integer $n$.

My conjecture: Let $n$ be a positive integer, $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ be odd prime numbers, and $n\ge2p_1$, ($n\ge6$)

There is at least one prime number $p_2$, so that $n^2 < p_2 \le n^2 + n - p_1$, and there is at least one prime number $p_3$, so that $n^2 + n - p_1 \le p_3 < (n + 1)^2$

Comment: Firstly, at the start you seem to fix $n,p_1,p_2,p_3$ but later you assert some $p_2,p_2$ exist, you may want to clarify that. Secondly, what even is your question?

Comment: @Wojowu I interpreted their question as "For any $n \geq 6$, there are primes $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ such that $n^2 < p_2 \leq n^2 +n -p_1$ and there is another prime $p_3$ such that $n^2 + n - p_1 \leq p_3 \leq (n+1)^2$.

Comment: @Josh or maybe the question is, for any $n\ge6$, and any odd prime $p_1$ with $n\ge2p_1$, there exist primes $p_2$ and $p_3$ such that etc., etc.

Comment: It's not clear why the title, "equivalent proposition of Legendre's conjecture." The conjecture proposed here is clearly implies Legendre's, but I don't see any implication going the other way.

Comment: Your question does not have a question mark anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your conjecture for sufficiently large $n$ is implied by [Cramer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture). In general though, conjectures like this unless they are coming from some specific application aren't that interesting. It is very easy to make many similar conjectures.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment of this question, however Legendre's conjecture is interesting (more so than say the more demanding assertion that for all sufficiently large $n$ the interval $[n, n + n^{1/1000})$ contains a prime, say) because it is the order of magnitude where we can prove that such short intervals contain primes, assuming the Riemann hypothesis. The fact that what you can get from RH is so far from what's predicted by Cramer's conjecture is by itself astounding; somehow primes in short intervals is harder than RH.